# Yii user module error

Tags: module, yii

I have installed 1.1.9 Yii framework.Then I made copy paste user module in my application folder and made changes to my main.php file.After all the configuration when I browsed the app and used user/login to login into my application, it showed error like this

```
Alias "user.UserModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file.
```

I have checked my main.php files many times.But why it is showing error like this?any help,suggestions will be highly appriciable.
Here is my main.php file code.

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
  'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
  'name'=>'My Web Application',

  // preloading 'log' component
  'preload'=>array('log'),

  // autoloading model and component classes
  'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    #user module starts
    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
    #user module ends
  ),

  'modules'=>array(
      'user'=>array(
        'returnUrl'=>array('/site/index'),
      ),
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
      'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
      'password'=>'XXXX',
       // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
      'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

  ),

  // application components
  'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
      // enable cookie-based authentication
      'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
      'loginUrl'=>array('/user/login'),
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    /*
    'urlManager'=>array(
      'urlFormat'=>'path',
      'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
      ),
    ),
    */
    //'db'=>array(
    //  'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    //),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
    'db'=>array(
      'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX',
      'emulatePrepare' => true,
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
      'tablePrefix'=> 'tbl_',
    ),
    'errorHandler'=>array(
      // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
    'log'=>array(
      'class'=>'CLogRouter',
      'routes'=>array(
        array(
          'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
          'levels'=>'error, warning',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
        /*
        array(
          'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
        ),
        */
      ),
    ),
  ),

  // application-level parameters that can be accessed
  // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
  'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the error. The user module should be made copy paste under protected directory.Not any other directory.

Comment: In fact it's only the sub-directory user from the archive that you have to put into the directory protected\user\

  So after having the files copieds you will get a structure like this :

 protected \ user \ assets
                  \ components
                  \ controllers
                  \ docs
                  ...
                  UserModule.php


  A lot of change that you will need also to edit your php.ini to 
 activate the short tags like this :

short_open_tag = On

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a custom user module class? Based on     'application.modules.user.models.*', it seems like you do. In that case I think you'll need to set the class in the module declaration as well.